# jQuery - Toggle Image Expand/Close

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

I have a dashboard pretty much a rip off of BBC.com which allows you to minimise and and expand the widget by clicking on a button.

When you've clicked on it, the image changes to indicate the widget is expanded or minimized.

Does anyone know how to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Example:

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

If you want something to slide up and down you can try this:

```
   var visible = true;

    $("button").click(function () {
          $("p").slideToggle("slow", function () {
            visible = !visible;
            if (visible)
            {
              $('icon').attr('src', 'url_to_downimage.jpg');
            }
            else
            {
              $('icon').attr('src', 'url_to_expandimage.jpg');
            }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I would say the same but this answer would be sufficient if you expounded on it a little more.  Give an example of how to use Toggle to do both tasks, opening and closing the tab as well as toggling the icon that makes it evident.

Comment: Okay great.  Also, you can add that this can be put into an each function so it can apply to multiple widgets.  I am unsure if BBC has many widgets, but assuming it does, it would work.