# jQuery - Toggle CSS Background Image Expand/Close

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, background-image

I am looking for a way to change the back ground image on toggle as in this questions here:

[jQuery - Toggle Image Expand/Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681638/jquery-toggle-image-expand-close)

My issue is I have this html:

```
<button id="close-menu"></button>
<div id="menu-bar">
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="image.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="options">
        <h2>eBlast Tools</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="toggle-images">Images are <span>enabled</span>. Click to disable.</li>
            <li class="download-zip"><a href="download.zip">Download ZIP File</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my current jquery:

```
$('#close-menu').click(function() {
    $('#menu-bar').slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

and this is the css:

```
#close-menu {
background: url(../img/minus-button.png);
background-position: top left;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 20px;
z-index: 100;
border: none;
}

#close-menu:hover {
background: url(../img/minus-button.png);
background-position: bottom left;
}
```

Comment: @HarshitTailor I have an image of a plus sign with a hover state, when this menu is open I have a minus image and a hover state. I am trying to figure out how to change this background image so open it will be minus and closed it will be a plus sign

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want the background of `close-menu` to change - try something like this:

```
$('#close-menu').click(function() {
    $('#menu-bar').slideToggle(400, function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $('#close-menu').css('background-position','bottom left');
        } else {
            $('#close-menu').css('background-position','top left');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

---

**In response to your comment** - you would be better off to create some css like this:

```
.minus { background: url(../img/minus-button.png) top left no-repeat; }
.minus:hover { background-position: bottom left; }

.plus { background: url(../img/plus-button.png) top left no-repeat; }
.plus:hover { background-position: bottom left; }
```

Add the class of `minus` to `close-menu` and then do:

```
$('#close-menu').click(function() {
    $('#menu-bar').slideToggle(400, function(){
        $('#close-menu').toggleClass('minus');
        $('#close-menu').toggleClass('plus');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry, I have an image of a plus sign with a hover state, when this menu is open I have a minus image and a hover state. I am trying to figure out how to change this background image so open it will be minus and closed it will be a plus sign.

Comment: No worries - it might be worth trying to have the two `toggleClass` bits as a callback of the `click` event rather than the `slideToggle` animation.

Comment: I will try that cause right now this is adding both minus AND plus classes on closed menu

Comment: @urbanrunic - it shouldn't do it if you add the minus class in yourself in the html (because the menu will be hidden by default)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if($('#divname:visible'))
 {
   $('#close-menu').css('background-image','img.jpg');
}
else
{
  $('#close-menu').css('background-image','img.jpg');
}
```